# Can't receive WhisperPush Messages on CM11

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms, textsecure

My Phone runs CyanogenMod 11. I registered in [WhisperPush](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_whispersystems_WhisperPush) via the Settingsentry and got the verification code. I do have a Google Account, the phone is new and I haven't installed any apps yet.

Now I wanted to text with my contact (he's using [TextSecure](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.thoughtcrime.securesms)) via WhisperPush/TextSecure. When he sends me a message using TextSecure, it's shown to him that it's sent encrypted, but I won't receive any message at all. On the other hand, when I send a message, it's send as a normal text without any encryption at all.

I tried to enter the verification code somewhere, but can't find anything, permissions should be also fine, at least I allow WhisperPush everything.

How can I get WhisperPush to work?

<sup>Hint: WhisperPush is [integrated with CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/whisperpush-secure-messaging-integration), so *Google Cloud Messaging* shouldn't be involved.</sup>

Update: I tried it with another contact, who uses TextSecure as well. While I still won't get any encrypted message and the messages I send are still plain text, after unregistering and re-registering from WhisperPush I noticed that I've the public key of my contact in my list, he had mine as well. So it seems there was a key-exchange, but somehow the messaging app(?) doesn't know it can communicate with this contact using WhisperPush/TextSecure.

Update II: I just installed the TextSecure (now Signal) app from the Google Play Store. Works flawless.

Comment: I can't find that app (could you provide a market link?), but it might be it uses Google Cloud Messaging. CM doesn't ship with the GApps, which are required for that. Do you have the Google Apps installed on that device?

Comment: @Izzy WhisperPush is directly shipped with CM [article](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/whisperpush-secure-messaging-integration). I do have (I guess all) Google Apps like GMail, Maps, PlayStore etc. It would be a bit weird if CM includes software which needs something you have to install afterwards...

Comment: Yupp, you're right. I wasn't aware of that fact (your question didn't state it ;) In that case, GCM shouldn't be involved here.

Comment: Yeah, but still don't know what to do. There was no other window or form I had to fill out/enter passphrase or so after receiving the verification code. I don't even know where to put it. So far it doesn't seem well thought through...

Comment: @Izzy: CM's WhisperPush implementation actually *does* require GCM. A ticket was filed at one point asking them to remove this requirement but it was [marked as "won't fix"](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-2953).

Comment: @eldarerathis That might answer the question then! Though I guessed it, you've got the proof. OP is unclear on whether Google Apps are installed (having an Google account doesn't necessarily mean to have GApps installed). If not: Mind making it an answer?

Comment: @Izzy, I'm quite sure I've the GApps installed. On the link eldarerathis provided they talk about the Play Service Framework. I guess it's the Google Service Framework which I have and according to the Privacy Guard has all permissions, not sure if there lies the problem.

Comment: Ok, I found an interesting thing. According to the App ops (advanced menu of the Privacy Guard), the Service Framework is said to be able to receive SMS, but when I look at the actual settings there is no option there to either restrict it or not. Seems like there should be this option, but actually it's missing. Could this be the problem?